# Which linux distro is more suitable for me

Tags: linux, ubuntu, distributions

I am new in `Linux` environment. I am currently using the `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` but it's not running as i expected, because my `PC` don't have high configuration.

Here's my system configuration

```
Memory : 2.9 GiB
Processor : Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz × 2 
Graphics : Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2
OS Type: 32-bit
Disk : 75.5 GB
```

I am looking for another `Linux distro`, but i don't know which one will suit me.

Here are my questions:

I've heard about `Lubuntu`.

1) Does it fit my configuration ?

2) Can i use `Android Studio` in `Lubuntu` ?

3) What are the other suitable `Linux distros` for my configuration?

I also wants to know,

4) Which's your favorite `Linux distro` and Why ? :)

Comment: This is not the right platform for your question as it is too dependent on personal opinions. I would suggest you take it up/read more over at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-forums-50/

Comment: Question like: "Which is you favorite distro and Why" is not supported

Comment: Also be more specific about your requirements

Comment: What do you mean as fast as you expected? I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a 7 year old netbook. And it is faster than I expected! But that doesn't mean its fast. I didn't even expect it to run.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) here you have the minimum requirements.
Second question, [just a google search](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20studio%20minimum%20system%20requirements%20linux).
Third question [from Linux.org](https://www.linux.com/news/hardware/desktops/8248-linux-distros-for-older-hardware).
Fourth, For me is Ubuntu, but depends of what I want to do.

I recommend you, if you will use Gnu/Linux system, to use Google, I found all your answers in just 5 minutes of search.

Gnu/Linux systems are google friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux, look around your environment for friendly geeks or a local Linux user group. Ask them for advise/help.

Linux distributions are all built on the same (much more than less) software, what varies is exact versions used, some local patches, and configuration. There really aren't wide-reaching differences, regardless of the many claims that their distribution is just *so* much better than everything else (a little secret, users on foot are usually up on arms on "defending" their distribution; while the developers work together, filching patches and reporting/checking bugs for others). You will need the help of somebody knowledgeable to start, and it is easier (and more fun) for them if they know their way around.